# How can I force removal of a linked CD image in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image

I recently was installing Fedora in a VM. The install went fine, so I moved the CD image off of my desktop into my general Linux ISOs folder. The next time I opened VirtualBox, I got an error saying it couldn't find the Fedora ISO. I launch the Virtual Media Manager to remove it and it won't let me. I've checked to ensure it's ejected from the VM, it appears to be. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably still inserted in the virtual CD/DVD drive in a snapshot. Go in and delete the snapshot tree and then try removing it.